# azkaban 3.0 jobs id doesn't change

Tags: azkaban

I'm trying to do some testing with Azkaban 3.0. Currently I'm facing a problem whenever I kick off a project that I already kicked off. So, before the execution id is assigned for the new run, it will be the same as the last execution id used for previous run, which results in the job not being executed. I'm pretty sure that this is an abnormal behavior, I tried restarting azkaban, but the problem still exists. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

got it fixed. apparently Azkaban doesn't work well with IE so I had to switch to chrome and its working fine now.